# Create a batch file to open CMD and enter a command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have created a batch file in an attempt to add a scheduled task however when this runs it does not execute the command any ideas?

```
echo off
Start CMD /k 
From CMD /k SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN “Cache Task” /TR “C:\Temp Batch     Two.bat” /ST 09:00
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `start cmd /k` will open a new command window.
- `from` is not a command, so will just emit an error message

A batch file *is* already a sequence of commands to execute. So if you want to execute commands in a batch file, then just do so (and incidentally, use straight quotes instead of typographic ones, as the latter won't work):

```
SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Cache Task" /TR "C:\Temp Batch Two.bat" /ST 09:00
```

(I also assume the batch file you want to run doesn't contain five spaces.)